# Debugging shell extensions in Win 7 and 8.1

Tags: windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging, shell-extensions

I would genuinely appreciate help with this. I have spent hours trying to solve it.

I wrote a small extension with VCPP6 (yes, I know. no need to tell me) to display the content of a particular DOS file as a thumbnail in Explorer using IExtractImage under XP. Debugging proved easy - I shut down explorer and hit F5. Clicking a file of the desired type resulted in a thumbnail. Breakpoints all active.

Upgrading to VS2012 (same happens with VS2013 Express) and using IThumbnailProvider, the same sequence doesn't work.

The program itself works. I can display the thumbnails in both 7 and 8.1. What I can't do is debug it via Explorer. I can debug it using a sample from the SDK (ThumbnailProvider) but not Explorer.

Project settings are:

```
Debugging->Command: C:\Windows\explorer.exe
Debugging->Command Arguments: /e,/select,F:\NewWork\NSD-24kW\pcb\15300003.pcb
Debugging->Working Directory: $(ProjectDir) (I've tried $(OutDir) too)
Debugging->Attach: No (I've tried 'yes' too)
Debugging->Debugger Type: Native Only
Debugging->Environment: (not set)
Debugging->Merge Environment: Yes
```

Searching for every variant I can dream up for debugging shell extensions and trying every possible variation on the guidance I can find, but it still does not see the breakpoints.

Comment: It's possible that the extension is now hosted by dllhost.exe instead of explorer.exe. You can use systinternals' procexp.exe tool to find out: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Hi, Simon. Thank you for the suggestion. With ProcessExplorer, dllhost.exe pops up when I click on a file and then disappears. I've tried all the obvious stuff plus all the ideas I can find by Googling and still no breakpoints enabled. Ho-hum.

Answer (score 2):

The extension is now probaby not hosted in explorer.exe, but in dllhost.exe (a Windows feature that isolates possibly buggy extensions from a critical Windows process).

You can configure it to be hosted inprocess with explorer.exe to ease debugging, as documented here: [C++ Windows Shell thumbnail handler (CppShellExtThumbnailHandler)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppShellExtThumbnailHandler-32399b35)

> Debugging thumbnail handlers is difficult for several reasons.
>
> 1) The Windows Explorer hosts thumbnail providers in an isolated
>   process to  get robustness and improve security. Because of this it is
>   difficult to debug  your handler as you cannot set breakpoints on your
>   code in the explorer.exe  process as it is not loaded there. The
>   isolated process is DllHost.exe and  this is used for other purposes
>   so finding the right instance of this process  is difficult.
>
> 2) Once a thumbnail is computed for a particular file it is cached and
>   your  handler won't be called again for that item unless you
>   invalidate the cache  by updating the modification date of the file.
>   Note that this cache works  even if the files are renamed or moved.
>
> Given all of these issues the easiest way to debug your code in a test
>   application then once you have proven it works there test it in the
>   context  of the explorer.
>
> Another thing to do is to disable the process isolation feature of
>   explorer.  You can do this by putting the following named value on the
>   CLSID of your  handler
>
> HKCR\CLSID{CLSID of Your Handler}
>
> ```
>    DisableProcessIsolation=REG_DWORD:1
> ```
>
> Be sure to not ship your handler with this on as customers require the
>   security and robustness benefits of the isolated process feature.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a small program to create a thumbnail from a file with this DLL. This program can easily be run under the debugger.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <Windows.h>

#include <ObjBase.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <Thumbcache.h>
#include <Unknwn.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Ole32.lib")

// Our GUID here:
LPCOLESTR myGuid = L"{9B083210-C856-48C0-8E8A-D9367301F046}";

typedef HRESULT ourDllGetClassObjectT(REFCLSID rclsid, REFIID riid, void **ppv);


int main(int c, char **v)
{
    GUID clsid = {0};
    IIDFromString(myGuid, &clsid);

    if (c < 3) { printf("not enough arguments: dll image\n"); return 1; }
    HRESULT r;
    IStream* pStream = NULL;
    HMODULE dll = NULL;

    dll = LoadLibraryA(v[1]);
    if (!dll) { printf("can't open DLL\n"); return 1; }

    ourDllGetClassObjectT *ourDllGetClassObject = (ourDllGetClassObjectT*) GetProcAddress(dll, "DllGetClassObject");

    IClassFactory *pFactory = NULL;
    r = ourDllGetClassObject(clsid, IID_IClassFactory , (void**) &pFactory);
    if (r != S_OK) { printf("failed: get factory: %08x\n", r); return 2; }

    IInitializeWithStream *pInit;
    r = pFactory->CreateInstance(NULL, IID_IInitializeWithStream, (void**) &pInit);
    if (r != S_OK) { printf("failed: get object\n"); return 3; }
    pFactory->Release();

    IThumbnailProvider *pProvider;
    r = pInit->QueryInterface(IID_IThumbnailProvider, (void**) &pProvider);
    if (r != S_OK) { printf("failed: get provider\n"); return 5; }

    wchar_t wfile[256] = {0};
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, v[2], -1, wfile, 256);
    r = SHCreateStreamOnFileEx(wfile, STGM_READ, 0, FALSE, NULL, &pStream);
    if (r != S_OK || !pStream) { printf("can't open file\n"); return 10; }

    r = pInit->Initialize(pStream, 0);
    pInit->Release();
    pStream->Release();
    if (r != S_OK) { printf("failed: init provider\n"); return 11; }

    HBITMAP bmp;
    WTS_ALPHATYPE alpha;
    r = pProvider->GetThumbnail(256, &bmp, &alpha);
    pProvider->Release();
    if (r != S_OK) { printf("failed: make thumbnail\n"); return 12; }

    printf("done");
}
```