# Debugging - Windows Explorer Thumbnail Handler Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, visual-studio-debugging, explorer

Windows Explorer Thumbnail Handler

Once again I'm at the mercy of the outside world because Microsofts
documentation is lacking or is not up to date, or total BS.

Using VS2010 I've created a Thumbnail handler (as an ATL) project.
I've changed the project so it compiles for x64 because I'm developing
on Windows 8.1 64 bit computer.

After the build I register the dll via the regsvr in the \Windows\system32 folder, I
get a message that states the registration is ok. Using ShellExView I can see that
my dll is install and registered.

Now comes the question that everyone seems to know but nothing has worked for me is 
how to debug the code. As I've said I added nothing to the original code but I've
placed break points at every function I can file. I see no other extension registered
to the PLT extension.

I set the debug app to C:\Windows\explorer.exe c:\somefolder\ that contains *.plt files.
In the debug Output window I never see my dll get loaded, so of course no break points
should be hit.

I've tried executing vs2010 as admin and not admin, I've tried killing all explorers before
starting the debugging one and nothing.

So whats the secret?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What the interfaces do you implement in your thumbnail handler?

Comment: The interfaces are auto generated by vs2010 when I select ATL project as DLL and Thumbnail handler. I know I need to fill in with my code but do I have to do anything to the base code to just see whats getting called without actually doing anything?

Comment: Your extension implements IExtractmage or IThumbnailProvioder? How file is loaded to your extension? With IInitializeWithStream or IPersistFile? Or you don`t know?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging shell extensions in Win 7 and 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24232451/debugging-shell-extensions-in-win-7-and-8-1)

Answer (score 1):

Thumbnail handlers are loaded by Thumbnail Handler Extraction Host because of security reason. If you want your handler to be loaded by Explorer directly you must create additional registry DWORD value:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{GUID}\DisableProcessIsolation = 1
```

where {GUID} is CLSID of your handler.